# omp_set_num_threads always returns 0 and im unable to get thread num with omp_get_thread_num()

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a C++ class library that uses omp for parallelization. I noticed my problem when it always used up all cores on my processor no mather what omp_set_num_threads(threadCount) had as input.

So when investegating I realized that the only way to get num_threads to work was to not use the omp_set_num_threads() method, but set num_threads on the parallel directive like so:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
{
   int i = omp_get_thread_num();
   printf_s("Hello from thread %d\n", i);
}
```

In the above case the output is:

```
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 0
```

If I instead use the following:

```
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel //num_threads(4)
    {
        int i = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf_s("Hello from thread %d\n", i);
    }
```

The output is

```
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 0
```

However, I created a new project of type Win32 Console Application the omp_set_num_threads works and I get the output:

Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 2
Hello from thread 1
Hello from thread 3

I have to think that this has to do with the project type or some parameter on the project. Does anyone know what it might be?

Best regards
Richard

Comment: I should add also that I have the /openmp flag set

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem now, so this thread can be closed, unless someone can answer why this happends, explanation following:

The problem I had was the property Common Language Runtime Support in the property pages of my C++ project was set to No Common Language Runtime Support. We changed this since visual studio 2010 did not support intellisense for C++ applications with this setting set to "Common Language Runtime Support". But it seems the setting is needed for the threading to work as I explained above.

Anyone know why?

Best regards
Richard

Answer (score 0):

OMP is not obliged to parallelize your code in any way at all. It may well judge that it's pointless parallelizing such short code - especially since printf contains no thread guarantees and performing blocking work in a parallel fashion is an anti-pattern. When dealing with threads, short snippets like this are never indicative of anything.

Comment: That's just a shortened code for clarity, I have a more complex code to parallel. I still dont get the thread num from omp_get_thread_num()